# TFS2013: code does not compile on Buildbox but does on Dev box

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild

I have an `Asp.net 4.0` solution that compiles properly on each local development machine using `VS2010` but when I run a build on our build box it gives me this error

```
ASPNETCOMPILER: Could not load file or assembly 'MagickNet' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

I have installed Imagemagik on the build box which has the `VC++` runtime required, changed the build configuration to Mixed Platform, Any CPU; but still the error keeps coming. The buildbox doesn't have any visual studio installation. Its a `win2012 R2` server with `.Net 4.0 framework` installed. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried forcing a 32-bit process? This is a common source of problems.

This option is in the Build Definition under [Advanced, MSBuild Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647547.aspx).

You can troubleshoot the dependencies for `MagickNet` using a tool like ILSpy or Reflector.

Comment: Did you mean changing it from Auto to X86? That creates problems for other dlls that are not 32 bit.